# keep NA and blanks rows in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataset:

```
ID FARM WEIGHT
1   2    NA
2   2    
3   3    57
4   4    58
5   7    NA
```

And I desire select the blank and NA rows, I need my data.frame this way:

```
 ID FARM WEIGHT
 1   2    NA
 2   2    
 5   7    NA
```

I tried this code:

```
newfile <- dataset[!(is.na(dataset$WEIGHT) | dataset$WEIGHT != ''),]
```

but doesn't work, I obtained an empty dataset.

Comment: Are you sure that the script you showed us is what actually generated that error message?

Comment: `df[is.na(df$WEIGHT) | df$WEIGHT == '', ]` seems to work for me.

Comment: Please have a look at [this demo](https://rextester.com/CINRA88378), where you may see your code, slightly modified, working as expected.

Comment: Sorry, @TimBiegeleisen, I need to edit my question.

Comment: So, I obtained an empty data.frame. Sorry about that.

Comment: Use `dput(head(df))` to show us a working sample of your data frame

Comment: @Sotos, is a big dataset. I think is very problematic to show you. Sorry.

Comment: Not the whole thing. Just the head...`dput(head(df))`. Otherwise we won't be able to help you

Comment: I understood, but I have 124 columns, man. heheheh...

Comment: You understand why I am asking right? Because you have an example in your question, and a piece of code that works great on that example. And as a result you will get answers like the one posted

Comment: @Sotos, Sure, because is easier to help me. I appreciate your attention. And I so sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. As it is, my best guess would be that you get an empty data frame because there are no NAs or empty cells, or because the empty cells are not really empty, and the NAs are not real NAs (maybe they are strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried you code, shouldn't you use `dataset[is.na(dataset$WEIGHT) | dataset$WEIGHT=="",]`?  The following code works.

```r
dataset <- data.frame(ID=1:5, FARM=c(2, 2, 3, 4, 7), WEIGHT=c(NA, "", "57", "58", NA) )

dataset[is.na(dataset$WEIGHT) | dataset$WEIGHT=="",]

#   ID FARM WEIGHT
# 1  1    2   <NA>
# 2  2    2       
# 5  5    7   <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use-

```
dt[!complete.cases(dt), ]
```

**OR**

```
dt[rowSums(is.na(dt) | dt=="") > 0,]
```

**Output**-

```
   ID FARM WEIGHT
1  1    2     NA
2  2    2     NA
5  5    7     NA
```

**Note**- If you want to `read` directly from file then you can also do-

`dt<- read.csv("file.csv", na.strings=c("NA",""))`